# How to programmatically detect whether UAC is enabled in Windows 8 using C++?

Tags: c++, windows-8, uac

In Windows XP / Windows 7 I could check the registry to determine if UAC is enabled, but this trick just isn't working with Windows 8.

```
BOOL FileOps::IsUacEnabled()
{
    LPCTSTR pszSubKey = _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System");
    LPCTSTR pszValueOn = _T("EnableLUA");
    DWORD dwType = 0;
    DWORD dwValue = 0;
    DWORD dwValueSize = sizeof( DWORD );

    if ( ERROR_SUCCESS != SHGetValue( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, pszSubKey, pszValueOn, 
        &dwType, &dwValue, &dwValueSize) )
    {
            return FALSE;
    }

    return dwValue != 0;
}
```

This function always return that the UAC is enabled when used from Windows 8.
Other methods I've seen fail as well:

```
HANDLE hToken; 
TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE elevationType; 
DWORD dwSize;

OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken); 
GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenElevationType, &elevationType, sizeof(elevationType), &dwSize);

bool bUAC_Enabled = false;

switch (elevationType) { 
case TokenElevationTypeDefault: 

  wprintf(TEXT("\nTokenElevationTypeDefault - User is not using a split token.\n")); 
  break; 
case TokenElevationTypeFull: 

  wprintf(TEXT("\nTokenElevationTypeFull - User has a split token, and the process is running elevated.\n")); 
  break; 
case TokenElevationTypeLimited: 

  wprintf(TEXT("\nTokenElevationTypeLimited - User has a split token, but the process is not running elevated.\n")); 
  break; 
}

if (hToken) { 
CloseHandle(hToken); 
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: UAC cannot be disabled on Windows 8.  So just check the OS version, can't get more pragmatic than that.

Comment: Isn't UAC always enabled on Windows 8? That could be why it's always returning `true`. (Otherwise... how did you try turning it off to check?)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that turning off UAC in Windows-8 is different from Windows-7. Sliding the bar down in the "Change User Account Control settings" screen functions differently on Windows-8. It is not disabling UAC at all.
The following [LINK](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/windows8/user-account-control-uac-144462) says: 
To really disable UAC ( On Windows-8 ), you would have to modify the EnableLUA value in the registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System to a value of 0 and reboot, but this is not a supported state of the OS and will block the modern applications-- so don't do this.

[Edit]: This site claims it is possible to turn off UAC on Windows 8 without creating problems for MarketPlace apps, using Group Policies:
http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000687.htm#.UOnBsm_FWrs

Very surprising... seems I will have to change many parts of my program to support UAC :(